# How to insert data into table as per Json object value using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need one help. I need to insert multiple data as per some Json object value into table using PHP and MySQL. I am explaining my code below.

```
$commnt=[{
   'day_id':2,
   'comment':'vodka1'
},{
  'day_id':3,
  'comment':'vodka2'
}
]

$result=[{
    'day_id':1,
    'restaurant':'193'
},{
  'day_id':2,
  'restaurant':'193'
},{
  'day_id':3,
  'restaurant':'193'
}
]
```

Here i need to enter all data from both Json object into this below table as per `day_id`. I am explaining column of my table below.

> db_details:

```
id   day_id   restaurant  comment
```

Here my requirement is when `day_id` will same the respective `comment` field value will entry into table other wise the `comment` filed value will remain blank.The expected out put is given below.

```
id    day_id   restaurant   comment

1       1        193               

2       2        193         vodka1

3       3        193         vodka3
```

My query is given below.

```
$insertintodetails=mysqli_query($connect,'INSERT INTO db_details
(day_id,restaurant,comment) values ("'. $result.'","'.$result[$i]['restaurant'].'","'.$commnt[$i]['comment'].'")');
```

Here there may be many use cases,like both Json object length may be same or different but the comment should insert as per `day_id` otherwise it will remain blank. In my query i can not insert as per required. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: $commnt is not an array, its a json object

Comment: where is your array()

Comment: Sorry,Please check my updated post.

Comment: still its a json.

Comment: you may use `json_decode` to some conversion to array

Comment: decode json to array using $commnt =  json_decode($commnt); and $result = json_decode($result);

Comment: My requirement is insert all data into table as per explainined above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I create an example from above your question detail. You can try below code. And it should work for you...

```
//For example taken array and convert it to JSON    
$comment = json_encode(array(array('day_id' => '2', 'comment' => 'vodka1'), array('day_id' => '3', 'comment' => 'vodka2')));
$result = json_encode(array(array('day_id' => '1', 'restaurant' => '193'), array('day_id' => '2', 'restaurant' => '193'), array('day_id' => '3', 'restaurant' => '193')));

//Convert JSON to array...
$arrComment = json_decode($comment, true);
$arrResult = json_decode($result, true);

foreach($arrResult AS $keyResult => $dataResult){
    $day_id = $dataResult['day_id'];//day_id
    $restaurant = $dataResult['restaurant'];//rasturant
    $strComment = '';//comment
    //Check and extract comment value from multi dimensional comment($arrComment) array...
    if($getComment = find_comment_with_dayid($arrComment, $day_id)){
      $strComment = $getComment;
    }

    //Insert records...
    $insertintodetails=mysqli_query($connect,'INSERT INTO db_details
(day_id, restaurant, comment) values ("'. $day_id .'","'. $restaurant .'","'. $strComment .'")');
}


//Function will return comment for matched day_id
function find_comment_with_dayid($arrComment, $fieldKey) {
    foreach($arrComment as $indCommenr => $dataComment) {
        //Check for day_id, matched then return comment...
        if($dataComment['day_id'] == $fieldKey) return $dataComment['comment'];
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Here, I taken example array for avoid JSON issue reported on your question. Hope this work well!

Comment: No,its working properly. `{"day_id":"2","restaurant":"193","comment":""}` is coming with blank comment value.

Comment: This could be greatly improved by consolidating the rows to insert into one statement, instead of one `INSERT` statement for each row. While it might not make much of a difference for small sets of data, it could be very beneficial as the application scales up. So for now, -1, but if you edit your post I will re-consider. For more info, see the [MySql reference section on INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = $insertintodetails = array();
foreach($result as $rs)
{
  $newArray[$rs->day_id] = [
    "`day_id`=>'{$rs->day_id}'",
    "`restaurant`=>'{$rs->restaurant}'"
];
}
foreach($commnt as $rs){
  $newArray[$rs->day_id][] = "`comment`='{$rs->comment}'";
}
foreach($newArray as $rs){
  $insertintodetails[]=mysqli_query($connect,'INSERT INTO db_details SET '.implode(',',$rs));
}
```

Comment: i will test and let you know.

Comment: @ hackout : in your code some foreach has missing `{}`.

Comment: its not working check your code properly.Many errors are coming.